# How to style parent element based on his child

Tags: css

Let's say our html structure looks like this:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Now on some button action I add `active` className to child's div.

My question is:

How to style only parent element if child's div has active className

// CSS pseudo code //

```
if(child.has.className('active')
.parent{
background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`:has()` pseudo class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), although that's [only supported in newer browsers](https://caniuse.com/css-has). Otherwise you'll probably need to use JS.

```css
.parent {
  background: #ccc;
}

.parent:has(.active) {
  background: steelblue;
  color: #eee;
}

/* Ignore below, for stylistic purposes only */
.parent {
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child active">Child (active)</div>
</div>
```

For a JS-based solution there are two ways:

- Recommended: in the code that adds the `active` class, you also toggle a class on the parent, say `has-active-child` and style it accordingly
- Not recommended: listen to class changes on the child node using [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and style the parent node

Answer (score 0):

At the moment not all browsers support the [pseudo class selector `:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) as Terry explained. A JavaScript solution goes as following.

Example from [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-apply-style-to-parent-if-it-has-child-with-css/)

```js
$('ul li:has(ul.child)').addClass('has_child');
```

```css
.parent > li > ul > li {
    background:orange;
}
.parent > li.has_child {
    background:red;
}
.parent li {
    background:blue;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .parent li {
            background:blue;
            color:black;
        }
        .parent > li > ul > li {
            background:orange
        }
        .parent > li > ul > li > ul >li {
            background:pink;
        }
    </style>
</head>
  
<body>
    <ul class="parent">
        <li>I am first</li>
        <li>I am second</li>
        <li>I am third</li>
        <li>I am forth</li>
        <li>I have kids.
            <ul class="child">
                <li>child1</li>
                <li>child2
                    <ul>
                        <li>child2.1</li>
                        <li>child2.2</li>
                        <li>child2.3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>child3</li>
                <li>child4</li>
                <li>child5</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>I am sixth</li>
        <li>I am seventh</li>
        <li>I am eight</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is really no need to use jQuery at all...

Comment: True, but I prefer the use of jQuery.